# Getting 415 error when trying to pass in multiple arguments to a get request in React with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

This might be easy (or hard) to answer, I'm new to react but haven't found a solution to my problem.

I made an api that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetDateRange")]
public IActionResult GetDateRange(DateRangeModel model)
{
 ...
}
```

So it takes in a DateRangeModel object. This object simply looks like this:

```
public class DateRangeModel
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now on the frontend, in react, I always seem to get a 415 (unsupported media error) no matter how I try to pass in the values. Here is my latest attempt with some hardcoded values:

```
var body = {
    playerId: 2, 
    startDate: '2020-01-01',
    endDate: '2020-03-03'
};

var myJson = JSON.stringify(body);

const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:64390/api/players/getdaterange/', myJson);
console.log(result);
```

When I enter this in the body in Postman it works perfectly and I get the 200 OK message along with the correct json response:

```
{
    "playerId": 2,
    "startDate": "2020-01-01",
    "endDate": "2020-03-03"
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because you are sending data to server you will have to use a `post` request. Right now you are using axios.get and you will need to replace it with axios.post. And you don't even need to use JSON.stringify method to parse the object into a string before axios.post method. Let me give a demonstration;

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:64390/api/players/getdaterange/', {
    playerId: 2, 
    startDate: '2020-01-01',
    endDate: '2020-03-03'
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

And you would need to handle this request on your server with a `post` request handler.

Comment: But then I will get 405 method not allowed. Or should I change my api to be Post rather than Get?

Comment: Thanks, it works with the post request now. I'm not sure why I didn't think of doing that, I guess I just assumed since I wasn't updating the database I should use get.

Comment: @JEvansPritchard Whichever http method you are using, you must handle it at your api end point with exactly same method. This is nothing to do with language or any framework. This is how web works

Comment: @JEvansPritchard Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JEvansPritchard Same here !